# connection error with spring cloud kafka stream

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to connect kafka streams on one of the hosted kafka providers authentication type is SASL_SSL
below is my application.yml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kafka:
        binder:
          brokers: ark-01.srvs.cloudkafka.com:9094,ark-02.srvs.cloudkafka.com:9094,ark-03.srvs.cloudkafka.com:9094
          configuration:
            security:
              protocol: SASL_SSL
          jaas:
            loginmodule : org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="un" password="pwd"
        sasl :
          jaas :
            config : org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="un" password="pwd"

      bindings:
        greetings-in:
          destination: 2wow01xi-default
          contentType: application/json
        greetings-out:
          destination: 2wow01xi-default
          contentType: application/json
```

I am not able to connect please advise.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code as text, not an image

Answer (score 0):

`...jaas.loginModule` requires upperCase `M`

Try

```
    binder:
      jaas:
        loginModule : org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule
        options:
          username: un
          password: pwd
```

Comment: Here is a working sample of how you can configure security. Look at the configuration. https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/multibinder-samples/kafka-multibinder-jaas

Comment: Its not working since I am using kafka as a service and security protocol is as below  security.protocol: SASL_SSL

Comment: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: KrbException: Cannot locate default realm

Comment: @gary-russell any help

Comment: See [the kafka documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/). Create a consumer (or producer) using the native `kafka-clients` directly (no Spring). Once you get that working, compare the INFO log that kafka prints to the one with Spring in the picture; if you can't figure it out; edit your question to show both logs.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved above issue using below configuration @gary-russell please confirm if its right approach

```
    spring:
        cloud.stream:
           bindings:
    greetings-in:
      destination: ms-dev-logs
      contentType: application/json
      binder: kafka1
    greetings-out:
      destination: ms-dev-logs
      contentType: application/json
      binder: kafka1
  binders:
    kafka1: 
    type: kafka
    environment:
        spring:
          cloud:
            stream:
              kafka:
                binder.brokers: ipaddr:9092,ipaddr9092,ipaddr:9092
                streams :
                  binder :
                    configuration :
                      default.key.serde: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde
                      default.value.serde: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerde

  kafka.binder:
    configuration:
      security.protocol: SASL_PLAINTEXT
      sasl.mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-256
kafka:
  properties:
    sasl:
      jaas:
        config : org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required username="usr" password="pws";
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the issue is with spring cloud kafka library and spring cloud team will be fixing it in next release, details can be found at

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/460